Why thread name is DefaultDispatcher-worker even though I specify function to run on Dispatchers.IO? And why the number of threads is so high?
A beginner question about how dispatchers work in Kotlin. I run this piece of code to test a theory and it printed out the thread names are "DefaultDispatcher-worker-xx" even though I specifically call launch(Dispatchers.IO). I never actually see the log showing as Dispatchers.IO anywhere in my code despite using withContext(Dispatchers.IO) in various places. How does it work?
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking {
    println("${Thread.currentThread().name} - Start")
    repeat(50) {
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) { performIO(it) }
    }
}

suspend fun performIO(number: Int) {
    println("${Thread.currentThread().name} - Perform IO $number")
    delay(2000L)
}

// even this doesn't show as expected
suspend fun performIO(number: Int) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    println("${Thread.currentThread().name} - Perform IO $number")
    delay(2000L)
}

The log looks like this
main - Start
DefaultDispatcher-worker-24 - Perform IO 18
DefaultDispatcher-worker-32 - Perform IO 30
.....
DefaultDispatcher-worker-12 - Perform IO 11
DefaultDispatcher-worker-17 - Perform IO 13

And second question, it says here in the document: By default, the maximum number of threads used by this dispatcher is equal to the number of CPU cores, but is at least two. My laptop has 10 CPU cores, but the log here shows the thread name ranging from 1 to 5x. It's likely around 50 different threads? Why?

"It's likely around 50 different threads? Why?": That's because your code runs on the IO dispatcher, and that dispatcher has a large Thread pool. This still doesn't answer your initial question though why the thread names look like the threads would belong to the default dispatcher instead (which they don't).

This behavior is explained in the documentation for Dispatchers.IO:

This dispatcher and its views share threads with the Default dispatcher, so using withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { ... } when already running on the Default dispatcher typically does not lead to an actual switching to another thread.

Dispatchers.Default and Dispatchers.IO actually share the same pool of threads. This allows to avoid the context switch in many cases, increasing the performance.
I never looked into it deeper, but I suppose when switching Default->IO, we keep executing in the same thread, we only signal the Dispatchers.Default we freed the slot. When switching IO->Default we need to verify if there are free slots and either execute directly or suspend.
This also answers why there are so many Default threads. Contrary to names, these threads are for both Default and IO. And potentially for other standard dispatchers in the future. At least for IO we need 64 threads by default.

Thank you, that explains the thread name. Does that mean we'd never see threads for IO, something like  IODispatcher-thread, etc? And Default and IO under the hood actually operate on the same thread pool?

I can't be 100% sure about this, but yes, I believe in the current implementation for JVM we won't see threads referencing the IO in their name.
